# Spring - Json Object sends values as array's and doesnt show field names

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

[PostMan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPp8x.png)

As you can see the data is something like :

```
[
 [
  2,
  "second title"
 ]
]
```

When it should be :

```
[
 [
  upvte : 2,
  title : "second title"
 ]
]
```

**My Spring Controller**

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private PostService postService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/listPost" ,produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    public @ResponseBody List<Post> listPosts(){

        return postService.getAll();

    }
```

**Post.Java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "text")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "upvote")
    private int upvote;

    @Column(name = "downvote")
    private int downvote;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "date_created",nullable = false)
    private Date dateCreated;
```

I'm Trying to map this response into Angular but I think because the fields are not shown in the reponse, The Angular can't map it .

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Can you share your pom dependencies?

Comment: share your pom.xml. Your code is fine, Check if you have Jackson dependency added.

Answer (score -1):

as @LHCHIN commented, my Question was duplicate and also to fix this issue : in your hibernate query you should add `addentity()` to your query which solves this issue